# Does "history.pushState" change web page content?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5-history

I'm a beginner, hope some help to understand these questions, thanks~

For web pages like youtube.com, it uses ajax + history:

1. does a "pushState" reload the page?
2. if I injected some java scripts into this web page, will DOM Element I injected be removed or replaced? when will this happen?
3. if this happens, how to re-inject DOM element to make it displayed, or how to prevent the DOM element from being removed...?

Comment: You have to care about the content, it's only some state saving. It's the "main" system of a 'dynamic' website

Comment: thanks~   confusing in the meaning of "care about the content"...

Answer (score 2):

> does a "pushState" reload the page

No. It changes the URL and stores some data (which you pass to it as an argument) in the history. It doesn't change the page at all.

You are expected to use `pushState` when  you write other code that changes the state of the page. (And you should change the state of the page so it is the same as if you freshly loaded the page at the URL you passed to `pushState`).

Then you are expected to change the state of the page back to host it was before (using the stored data) when you get a `popState` event.

Comment: thanks a lot! it's helpful. will try to learn something more. is there any examples.for reference?